# DigitalOcean: Getting Spaces credentials from an App

Tags: digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces, digital-ocean-apps

On DigitalOcean, I have an App and a Spaces Bucket with files.

I need my app to read and write on that bucket, therefore I need to provide it a Spaces Key and a Spaces Secret for my S3 Client.

However, I can't find any way to automatically provision those environment variables into a Digital Ocean App.

I tried to attach the Space to my app, but it is only possible with the databases. I also tried to use the [Resources specific variables in the app env vars](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/#resource-specific-variables) but nothing is suggested with the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

What about using:

```
APP_ID=<your_app_id>
SPACES_KEY=<your_spaces_key>
SPACES_SECRET=<your_spaces_secret>
ACCESS_TOKEN=<your_digitalocean_access_token>

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
     -d '{
       "variables": [
         {
           "key": "SPACES_KEY",
           "value": "'"$SPACES_KEY"'"
         },
         {
           "key": "SPACES_SECRET",
           "value": "'"$SPACES_SECRET"'"
         }
       ]
     }' \
     "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/apps/$APP_ID/environment"
```

To automatically set those env vars?

Comment: Sure I could manually generate them, store them as a secret and inject those values using my CI. But both services being from the same provider and designed to be used together - I was expecting a little bit more comfort by having them automatically generated and injected by any manner :)